# random number generation and nested array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I am trying to generate random number for creating scatter plot with d3js. I am doing it in the following manner:

```js
//declare an array of arrays
var dataset = [
  []
];
var inner = [];

/*
    set the svg width and height
*/
var svgWidth = 500;
var svgHeight = 100;
var xCoord = 0;
var yCoord = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  do {
    xCoord = Math.floor(Math.random() * svgWidth);
    yCoord = Math.floor(Math.random() * svgHeight);
  } while (xCoord <= 0 | yCoord <= 0);


  if (xCoord > 0 && yCoord > 0) {
    inner.push(xCoord);
    inner.push(yCoord);

    dataset.push(inner);
  }

  inner = [];
}

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", svgWidth)
  .attr("height", svgHeight);


svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d[0];
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d[1];
  })
  .attr("r", 5);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

The outer array should contain only 20 elements, I found out that it is creating 21 elements instead with the first element with only the radius values and no coordinate value for the center of the circle. Some hint would be great to have to understand the issue.

Comment: `while( xCoord <= 0 | yCoord <= 0 )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
//declare an array of arrays
var dataset = [];
var inner = [];

/*
    set the svg width and height
*/
var svgWidth = 500;
var svgHeight = 100;
var xCoord = 0;
var yCoord = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  do {
    xCoord = Math.floor(Math.random() * svgWidth);
    yCoord = Math.floor(Math.random() * svgHeight);
  } while (xCoord <= 0 | yCoord <= 0);


  if (xCoord > 0 && yCoord > 0) {
    inner.push(xCoord);
    inner.push(yCoord);

    dataset.push(inner);
  }

  inner = [];
}

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", svgWidth)
  .attr("height", svgHeight);


svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d[0];
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d[1];
  })
  .attr("r", 5);
```

Comment: A bit confused though, How to declare nested arrays then in JavaScript. The book  - "Interactive Visualization for the Web" mentions that the nested hard brackets indicates an array within an array

Answer (score 3):

The inner array isn't necessary, in fact it's the problem.

```
var dataset = [
  []
];
```

Just remove it.

```
var dataset = [];
```